# Use of two dimensional array

Tags: php, sql

I am facing a problem while wanting to fetch all the rows from my following table namely `date`.

```
id      name       username    app      sdate    edate   
===    =======     ========    ===      =====    ======  
 1      tanvir      tanvir      1       2012      2012       
 2      Ranvir      Ranvir      1       2011      2013      
 3      john        john        2       2011      2012     
 4      Rakib       Rakib       1       2011      2012
```

I use the following MySQL Query:

```
$date = mysql_query("select * from `date`");
$date_row = mysql_fetch_array($date);
```

But it is only returning a single row.

How can I put all of the rows into a two dimensional array?

Comment: [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) ? You should use PDO and never call a table `date` because it's a mysql function.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @soyuka That's what backticks are for. Derp.

Comment: I know but it can be confusing sometimes (if you forget them for example) I think the best is just not to use them.

Answer (score 11):

Well of course it's only returning one row, that's what `mysql_fetch_array` does:

> mysql_fetch_array — Fetch ***a*** result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

Now, to build an array of your rows, you just have to iterate over them:

```
$all_rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($date)) $all_rows[] = $row;
```

Notice how I use `mysql_fetch_assoc` here. You should NEVER use `mysql_fetch_array` unless you very specifically need both numeric and associative indices.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date =  getQueryData("select * from `date`");
function getQueryData($sQuery)
{
    $result = mysql_query($sQuery); 
    $rows = Array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
       $rows[] = $row;
    }
    @mysql_free_result($result);    
    return $rows;
}
```